# How come it seems like all Lucy's Spirits can summon themselves?

Tags: fairy-tail

When Loki is one of Karen's spirits and he switches with Aries, he says he is not an ordinary spirit so he can switch with them and summon himself on his own but other spirits seem to have no problem summoning themselves.

If this was the case just for the Zodiac Keys, I would be "ok" but Horologium will show up without Lucy summoning him too whereas he is a regular spirit.

Comment: I didn't peg Aries as a masochist that she'd want to be abused and Karen planned to force Aries out for a week which would have killed her. Loke summoned himself to defend Aries and Karen, to my knowledge, only have Aries and Loke. Lucy's relationships with her Spirits to my understanding are way more healthier than Karen's so are more likely to summon themselves to help her (even Aquarius despite her usual temperament)

Comment: I realize why they are more likely to summon themselves but i'm wondering how they can since Loke makes it sound like he's the only one who can do it and like I said in the question Horologium has summoned himself (it was to protect Lucy from an explosion if l remember correctly).

Answer (score 3):

It is mentioned in the series that since Lucy and her spirits share a *strong bond*, the spirits can summon themselves without Lucy initiating it. It doesn't matter if it is a zodiac key or a silver key.

Moreover as her magic power increases, the time that they can remain in the real world also increases.

Answer (score 1):

Loki and Aquarius are strong. They can even help others spirits. The celestial spirits have bonds strong enough with Lucy than any other celestial wizard that fuel them some strength to do it for a some time. Only small amount of time because apart from Loki I have seen none who had stayed for long. Also there was a time when celestial God himself appeared. It took toll on Lucy than with most of spirits. So it also can happen that they use her strength. 
Just speculations....

Answer (score -1):

They all have magical power. It's like chakra in *Naruto*. It can't be used a lot, but also can't be overused. Their magical power can help them go through the world. Helping them enter the world takes a value amount of there so called magical ability. Therefore they like Lucy as their master to save her or do it at their own will to be there. Even Aquarius sometimes.

Other than Loke, he had no master. Before the time, he just has a lot of this power to enter the world. As I said, it all goes to waste for too long. I don't know if Loke had used his power on the ladies or if he just gets it. That's another question to be answered. Other than that, the answer is a sort of magical power, or if you want to say chakra.

Comment: I would understand if that were the case but then why would Loke say he's "special" in that he can come. this would be a possible way for things o work but it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I don't quite understand the way you're trying to ask the question.

Comment: basically why does Loki say he's special because he can come at will when everyone else seems to also be able to do it as well